# Problem in a pybind11, c++ project using makefile

Tags: c++, templates, makefile, header, pybind11

I want to export my cpp library in python using pybind11. I create a simple example of my library, you can see the example here:

[github example](https://github.com/GiulioPN/ex_cpp_pybind11)

This simple example give me some trouble, because it produce a "symbol(s) not found" error. I don't know where is the error.

The error is reported in the file "terminal_error".

My library is very similar to the example, but obviously is more complicated with lot of files. However if the example works then also the library works, because they share the same structure.

P.S. I'm using OSX Catalina

Comment: Hello Giulio, on Debian 10 I can compile and run your example. The error you have appears to be at link time, try to manually add a link to where `pybind` has been installed (with the `-L` flag). Alternatively you may use `gcc` instead of `clang` but I'm not too sure of what this implies on osX

Comment: Also, it would be easier to use `cmake`, you can find working examples in [the documentation](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/compiling.html)

Comment: Thanks @Christian, I forgot to update the question. The error was fixed some days ago for Linux system. I think you are right, in OS I have to link manually the pybind library. 

I know that the documentation for cmake is easier, but my initial project take of advantage of Makefile, so I don't want change the structure. 

Thanks again for the advices.

Comment: I'm not sure whether your problem is solved or not then ? If yes, it would be nice to explain your steps to solve the issue (or maybe the rationale as to what you did not understand correctly, this is also helpful) and the [mark your question as solved](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)